# How to get EditText of one line which scroll horizontally if text is long

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have set maxLines to 1 and scrollHorizontally to True but it's not working. It is giving multiline EditText which scrolls vertically.

```
       <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Work"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:lines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `EditTextin HorizontalScrollView`

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

try adding this property:

```
singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `singleLine="true"`

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextHorizontalScroll"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Work" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a solution, but I show you another way, with this way, your text view can auto slide if it is too long, very interesting.

```
                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="marquee_forever marquee_forever marquee_forever marquee_forever"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<EditText>` inside `<HorizontalScrollView>`